# Mathematical research institutes similar to Banff and Oberwolfach

Tags: mathematics

What other institutes such as these two exist for a visit by a scientist for an undisturbed period of short research? Ideally with a good landscape.
Dagstuhl is another one I found.

Comment: Welcome to HSMSE. What has your question to do with History of Science?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 of them in the USA are listed here:
https://aimath.org/news/postdoc/seveninstitutes.html
and there are more, for example, http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/institute-mathematical-sciences.

Not all of them have beautiful nature environment but MSRI certainly does.